# getting DeadObjectException after updating app from play store?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I have already installed previous version of my application. When I have submitted new version of my application on play store. on my mobile I have updated that new version but when I am going to use some functionality it is giving me following exception

```
Failed to dispatch window animation state change.
                                             android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                 at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.onAnimationStopped(IWindow.java:534)
                                                 at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:289)
                                                 at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:681)
                                                 at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.access$000(WindowAnimator.java:53)
                                                 at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:123)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:605)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

but when I have deleted that application and again downloaded from play store it is working fine all the functionality.

please help me to understand why this happening first time after updating application.

Answer (score 2):

This happened because your a Service or Component in your app has been stopped.

You need to override you Service's or Component's onDestroy() and catch any DeadObjectException to prevent the crash. It happens only when service is killed by OS or application stop.

In Android Developer Documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html
it is mention that DeadObjectException occurs when the object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.